# How to dynamically create list of <a> tags using js

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating html page which needs to create a list of links dynamically on a click of button. I know how to create this list when number of links to be created is known before like this:

```
    //For 4 tags:
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var aTag = document.createElement('a');
    aTag.innerHTML = "link1 text";
    aTag.setAttribute('onclick',"func()");
    mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
    var bTag = document.createElement('b');
    bTag.innerHTML = "link2 text";
    bTag.setAttribute('onclick',"func()");          
    mydiv.appendChild(bTag);
    var cTag = document.createElement('c');
    cTag.innerHTML = "link3 text";
    cTag.setAttribute('onclick',"func()");
    mydiv.appendChild(cTag);
    var dTag = document.createElement('d');
    dTag.setAttribute('onclick',"func()");
    dTag.innerHTML = "link4 text";
    mydiv.appendChild(dTag);
```

But the problem is that the count will be known at run time and also on function call i need to identify the id of link that invoked function.. Can anybody help?

Comment: What is giving you the list data ie what are `a/b/c/d Tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know weather you receive or not the HTML to be shown in the anchor, but anyway, this should do the work:

```
function createAnchor(id, somethingElse) {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.innerHTML = "link" + id + " text";
    anchor.setAttribute("onclick", "func()");
    return anchor;
}
```

Then you call the function like this:

```
function main(num_anchors) {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    for (var i = 0; i < num_anchors; i += 1) {
        mydiv.appendChild(createAnchor(i));
    }
}
```

Of course this code can be improved, but this is just for show how can this be possible.

Comment: Its quite helpful.. Is there any way to determine which tag (id of link) actually called the function because all tags are calling same method and its important to identify which tag invoked the function?

Comment: Yes, you can do something like this:
replace `code` anchor.setAttribute("onClick", "func()"); `code` with `code`  anchor.onclick = function(e) { var a = e.currentTarget; }; `code` so the var a is the current anchor clicked, then you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do this at runtime . 
JQuery provides very useful dom manipulation . So you can traverse the dom , filter what you need ..

you can find a lot of useful functions here . 
http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

It would look something like this.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

   $( "a" ).each(function( index ) { 

    // enter code here..
   }
});
```

document.ready gets invoked once the DOM has loaded.